# Плавное передвижение маркеров на карте

Tags: android, yandex-maps-api, yandexmapkit

Я использую yandex-mapkit. Как сделать плавное перемещение маркера на карте, при смене его геопозиции? Метод setGeometry не работает, объект резко перемещается(Рывками), а мне нужно, чтобы он перемещался плавно, как в яндекс такси.

Comment: подскажите как вы это делаете? ато вообще примеров нет..

Answer (score 1):

На уровне PlacemarkMapObject эту задачу не решить. 
Вы не знаете как именно нужно интерполировать значение между двумя точками.

Если это перемещение по автомобильной дороге, то стоит воспользоваться библиотекой guidance, которая умеет интерполировать геопозицию и притягивать ее к дорожному графу. Если же это произвольное перемещение, то интерполяцию нужно реализовать на стороне приложения, такую как требуется.